# sum last two rows of child group in parent group in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

How to sum last two rows in child group using SSRS!

I tried functions like `iif()`, `max()`, `runningValue()`, `sum()`, `rownumber()`, even `inscope()`.

But I can't figure out good way to do it.

I have groups like this:

```
-FirstParent
    + FirstChild    30
    + SecondChild   60
    + ThirdChild    90

-FirstParent
    -FirstChild
        Group1  10
        Group2  20
    -SecondChild
        Group1  40
        Group2  20
    -ThirdChild
        Group1  40
        Group2  50

-SecondParent
    + FirstChild    40
    + SecondChild   100
    + ThirdChild    60

-SecondParent
    -FirstChild
        Group1  20
        Group2  20
    -SecondChild
        Group1  40
        Group2  60
    -ThirdChild
        Group1  10
        Group2  50
```

But I want before FirstParent and Second Parent are expanded. I want to be shown Value of First Child, 
    Something like this.

```
+FirstParent    30
+SecondParent   40
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, the total of FirstChild is under Child level. However, you want to show this total on Parent level. We can only sum the value of Parent level based on the Child group name. Use the expression on Parent Group below:

=sum(IIF(Fields!Child.Value="FirstChild",Fields!Amount.Value,0))